# How to simulate file upload to blobstore using GAE dev server testbed for python

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, blobstore

Id like to write some unit tests that among other thing will need to [read a blobstore file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass?hl=pl)

How to write a unit test `setUp` that puts some file in [testbed](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting) blobstore so it will availabe for read this way:

```
blob_info = BlobInfo(blob_key)
reader = BlobReader(blob_info)
reader.readline()
```

**EDIT:**

I do not look for a way to test [files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview?hl=pl#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore), I want to put some arbitrary data in the testbed blobstore storage dusring the test case setUp phase, so I can run tests against this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following to your setUp method, and perhaps store the `blob_key` as `self.blob_key` for later use. The init_files_stub is important as it initializes the file service with the memory blobstore.

```
self.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
self.testbed.init_files_stub()
from google.appengine.api import files
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write('blobdata')
files.finalize(file_name)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

Note that testbed refers to `from google.appengine.ext import testbed` and `self.testbed` is the testbed instance.

With init_files_stub, this is exactly as described in [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore):

Comment: My first example works for me if I put it in setUp, it writes the 'blobdata' (can be image bytes or whatever) to a blob with id 'blob' and reader.read() in your example will return 'blobdata'. Save self.blob_key in setUp if you need the exact key in your test.
The second example seems like the appropriate way to do it according to APIs, but doesn't work. How did the first example fail when you tried to use it?

Comment: Sorry I did not test it yet, `should work` part of your answer confused ;) I did found a solution in the meantime, putting `BlobInfo` into datastore myself, like this: `datastore.Put(datastore.Entity('__BlobInfo__', name=file_path, namespace='')`. Your solution much prettier, thx mate!

Comment: First example works like a charm but, second examples fails for me on `create` with `AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "file"`. I did init the `init_blobstore_stub`. Is there another init method for `files` api stub?

Comment: You're right, my explanation was confusing, I've tried modifying it a bit, hope it helps. On testbed, I activate(), and init datastore_v3, memcache, taskqueue, blobstore and I don't see the AssertionError you mention. I don't know where it tries to use a 'file' service or how to init it.

Comment: With init_files_stub present, the API method works and should be preferred. I updated my answer accordingly.