# how to simulate image upload to google app engine blobstore

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm uploading images to the GAE blobstore using create_upload_url

```
uploadURL = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
```

For the purpose of unit testing the gae code, can you simulate the image upload? OR should I insert the image data in my test bed and assume the upload is successful? If so, how do you upload an image to the test bed?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @fredrik on what exactly you're testing there.

Anyway, if you're doing some functional/blackbox/similar testing, you could simply use [Webtest framework](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/modules/webtest.html) (see `post` method) and do the actual upload, e.g.

```
payload = [(fieldname, filename)]
test_app.post(uploadURL, upload_files=payload)
```

Have a look at [Handler Testing for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) for details on how to initialize the above test_app.

Comment: Hi Alex, You're correct. I'm actually targeting two aspects i) confirm the image upload worked and ii) create test objects to test other aspects of my GAE program. Using your example above, how would you generate payload data that represents a blob of content type image/jpeg?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly... `fieldname` is what's in your <form>... <input type="file" name="myfieldname">. `filename` is something like "tests/payloads/testimage.jpg"

Comment: 'filename' is what I don't entirely understand. I'm running this test on the server using GAEUnit. Is testimage.jpg generated on the fly? or previously stored on the server? or other?

Comment: Uh, so you're basically running unit tests on production servers? Well, in that case you could use `payload = [(fieldname, filename, file_content)]` where file_content is something like `blob_reader.read()` and filename is just a name for a "fake" file

Comment: or, instead of blob_reader.read() just read a file as you'd normally would in python.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provided some code on how your test look?

I think you should be able to fake a request to the upload_url using webapp2. Have a look [here](https://github.com/fredrikbonander/Webapp2-Sample-Applications/blob/master/sample-app-auth/tests/test_pac_auth.py) for some sample code on how to fake requests.

On the other hand you should think of what the purpose of your test is. Is the purpose to test that the image upload works or is it how your code works after the upload is complete?

When running unit-tests try to break the dependencies to other libraries so that you only test you own code. And then add a new suite of implementation test, ie make a request for and url and check that you get the expected response. As in `test_redirect_if_no_session` of the example above, make a request to a page that requires a user and expect a redirect (http response code 302).

..fredrik

Comment: Thank you. It appears I need to write two tests i) a test that check  upload_url operates correctly and ii) insert images into the blobstore to test other aspects of my GAE program. Presumably I can adapt this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870968/how-to-simulate-file-upload-to-blobstore-using-gae-dev-server-testbed-for-pytho but i'm not 100% sure how to adapt this to image data...?